# how to make carousel image slightly zoom before the fade transition

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap

i am build a website for a class, and i like the webpage www.sweetgreen.com and their images seem to slightly zoom before the fade transition. i got the fade but its quick and doesnt gracefully do that. i can probably figure that one out though, the slight zoom effect is what i would like to know how to do, i have inspected the element and applied some of the classes with the specifics in my bootstrap stylesheet for my rails app. this is my div

```
 `<div class="item">
     <%= link_to image_tag("carousel_img2.jpeg", :size => "1600x200", :alt =>
     "Slide2"), {:class => "img-responsive center-block", :alt => "Responsive  
      image"} %>
      <div class="carousel-caption text-center">

        </div>
```

Answer (score 1):

I have made a clear demo: https://jsfiddle.net/wyvguf25/

And this one is based on Bootstrap3: https://jsfiddle.net/q0rgL8ws/

The first one is using `opacity`.
For the Bootstrap one which is using `display`

Comment: i see, did you grab that css code from inspecting that sample website? i want to add typing as well to it just like that site in the middle and with similar effects.

Comment: Second link is working. But why the first slider of second link is not getting zoom effect ?

Answer (score 0):

```
@-webkit-keyframes move {
from {
transform: scale(1, 1);
-ms-transform: scale(1, 1); /* IE 9 */
-webkit-transform: scale(1, 1); /* Safari and Chrome */
-o-transform: scale(1, 1); /* Opera */
-moz-transform: scale(1, 1); /* Firefox */
}
to {
transform: scale(1.05, 1.05);
-ms-transform: scalescale(1.05, 1.05); /* IE 9 */
-webkit-transform: scalescale(1.05, 1.05); /* Safari and Chrome */
-o-transform: scalescale(1.05, 1.05); /* Opera */
-moz-transform: scale(1.05, 1.05);/* Firefox */

}
}
.item .zoomin {
animation:move 7s ease infinite; 
-ms-animation:move 7s ease infinite;
-webkit-animation:move 7s ease infinite;
-o-animation:move 7s ease infinite;
-moz-animation:move 7s ease infinite;
background-color:Black;
left:-150px;
top:-150px;
}
```

Its working with 1st slider that has zoom effect too.